# In swift how to copy a struct with one with only one different field

Tags: swift, scala, struct

If I have a swift struct

```
struct Person {
  let firstName: String
  let lastName: String
  let gender: Gender
  let height: Float
  let weight: Float
  let age: Int
}
```

If have an object `a` of type `Person`, from time to time, only one of the field changed, like `lastName` when the person gets married, age when the person had a birthday etc. but I don't want to create a `mutating func` for each of the fields, nor do I want to write a lot of boilerplate to construct a new struct passing in all those fields again. Is there a better to to achieve something like

```
let newPerson = oldPerson.copy(lastName = "Married")
```

I know this is a really neat feature in scala with case classes, but I have yet to see this feature used in swift. May I know how can I achieve this? Do you guys think it should be a baked in feature in swift? Maybe we can make a swift evolution proposal?

Comment: What's wrong with making the fields of your struct mutable (`var`)? Value semantics will ensure that you'll be working with a copy after mutation. You can always mark the setter of a property as having a lower access level than the getter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input, what I am asking is more about a language wide feature rather than how to achieve the effect that I want in a specific case. It sounds like it is not supported in s swift language, but I think it should.

Comment: But what I'm trying to tell you is that this is already a language feature ;) `var newPerson = oldPerson; newPerson.lastName = "Married"` is all you need to create a copy of a `Person` instance with a modified property – what advantages would a `copy()` method have over this (besides being on a single line)? Is it that you'd like to be working with `let` constants on the caller side?

Comment: @Hamish I see what your are saying. I strongly agree with you that your approach is better. I had tunnel vision when I was thinking about this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a struct and modify one of its properties at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331277/how-to-copy-a-struct-and-modify-one-of-its-properties-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is an elegant solution. One option would be to
define a copy method which takes optional parameters for each
property, which default to the current property values:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    func copy(firstName: String? = nil, lastName: String? = nil, age: Int? = nil) -> Person {
        return Person(firstName: firstName ?? self.firstName,
                      lastName: lastName ?? self.lastName,
                      age: age ?? self.age)
    }
}


let john = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 29)
let jane = john.copy(firstName: "Jane")
print(jane) // Person(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", age: 29)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this will only work for non-optional properties (I don't believe you can do any tricks with double wrapped optionals to make it work for optional properties)

Comment: @Hamish: It is possible, but not nice. If there is a optional property `let gender: String?` then copy would have a `gender: String?? = nil` parameter. Updating the property to `nil` requires that you call `copy(gender: Optional<String>.none)` or `copy(gender: nil as String?)`. `copy(gender: nil)` would leave it unchanged.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true – I was trying to think of a solution that would allow for both an input of `nil` and a new optional value for the property, with only the default argument value leaving the property unchanged. I suppose one alternative could be to use a triple wrapped optional, but that would have other flaws, such as allowing spurious double/triple wrapped optional input, not to mention being needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A `copy` function of `Person` can naturally have default value for its arguments, which would allow calling it with only a subset of the properties of person. The problem is that we may not use `self` to refer to what values we'd like to use as default. We can, however, refer to static members of a class (fir convenience, say static members of `Person`), which would allow us to create something along the lines

```
struct Person {
    static var currentObjFirstName: String = ""
    static var currentObjLastName: String? = ""
    // ...
    static var currentObjAge: Int = 0

    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String?
    // ...
    let age: Int

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String?, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }

    func prepareCopy() -> Person {
        Person.currentObjFirstName = self.firstName
        Person.currentObjLastName = self.lastName
        Person.currentObjAge = self.age
        return self
    }  

    func copy(firstName firstName: String = Person.currentObjFirstName, 
              lastName: String? = Person.currentObjLastName,
              age: Int = Person.currentObjAge) -> Person {
        return Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age)              
    }  

}
```

Example usage:

```
let foo = Person(firstName: "foo", lastName: "bar", age: 42)
let bar = foo.prepareCopy().copy(age: 21)
print(bar) // Person(firstName: "foo", lastName: Optional("bar"), age: 21)
let baz = foo.prepareCopy().copy(lastName: nil)
print(baz) // Person(firstName: "foo", lastName: nil, age: 42)
```

Possibly this solution goes under your description as *"... boilerplate to construct a new struct passing in all those fields again"*, though, and apart from that, `prepareCopy()` above isn't very pretty...

Comment: Using static properties as intermediate storage would break in a multithreaded environment. That might be relevant or not, but being thread-safe is one advantage of value types.