# Does Swift have an equivalent to Rust's struct update syntax?

Tags: swift

Rust has a nice feature they called the [Struct Update Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax), which is a convenient way of creating a new struct from an existing struct without explicitly supplying all the parameters you want to copy over.

Does Swift have an equivalent feature?

Comment: This is to short to post as an answer, but: Nope.

Comment: Closely related (if not duplicate): [How to copy a struct and modify one of its properties at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38331277/1187415)

Answer (score 4):

No.

(Extra text added to permit posting.)

Comment: Do you know if there are any existing proposals to add such a feature?

Comment: Why not look and see? Swift is community developed and open source. The forum is open to you as to anyone.

Comment: Because it's not obvious what such a feature would be called in swift, so I'm not sure what I'd search for. Rust has a specific name for it, but it's by no means a universal name.